# atualizar value do hidden antes de submit

Tags: jquery, html2canvas

Estou tentando atualizar dois hiddens com um código base64 vindo do plugin `html2canvas`, mais ele não atualiza e na outra página onde o formulário é recebido pego por `$_POST` os dois campos `hidden` mais não mostra o código `base64`.

```
html2canvas(document.getElementById("areamontagem"), {
    "useCORS": true,
      onrendered: function(canvas) {
          $( "#baseimg" ).val(canvas.toDataURL("image/png"));
      }
    });
    //print area total sem MOLDE
    html2canvas(document.getElementById("areamontagem"), {
    "useCORS": true,
      onrendered: function(canvas) {
          $( "#baseimg" ).val(canvas.toDataURL("image/png"));
      }
    });
    $( "#myform" ).submit();
```

Answer (score 2):

O problema acontece porque o código que gera a imagem em base64 é assíncrono, ou seja, ele roda fora da linha do tempo do seu código. Explico melhor:

```
// o javascript executa o html2canvas e ...
html2canvas(document.getElementById("areamontagem"), {
    "useCORS": true,
      onrendered: function(canvas) {
          $( "#baseimg" ).val(canvas.toDataURL("image/png"));
      }
});

// logo em seguida chama o html2canvas novamente e ...
html2canvas(document.getElementById("areamontagem"), {
    "useCORS": true,
      onrendered: function(canvas) {
          $( "#baseimg" ).val(canvas.toDataURL("image/png"));
      }
});

// logo em seguida chama o submit do form.
$( "#myform" ).submit();
```

Algum tempo depois o `callback` do `html2canvas` retorna, mas já é tarde demais e a página já foi submetida com o campo hidden vazio.

Ou você usa Promises (tem no jQuery e é simples de usar, apesar de não ser simples entender a princípio) ou você encadeia as chamadas dentro dos callbacks, assim:

```
html2canvas(document.getElementById("areamontagem"), {
    "useCORS": true,
      onrendered: function(canvas) {
          $( "#baseimg" ).val(canvas.toDataURL("image/png"));

          html2canvas(document.getElementById("areamontagem"), {
              "useCORS": true,
                onrendered: function(canvas) {
                    $( "#baseimg" ).val(canvas.toDataURL("image/png"));
                    $( "#myform" ).submit();
                }
          });
      }
});
```

Dessa forma o javascript chama o primeiro html2canvas, e quando ele retornar, chama o segundo e quando esse retornar o seu formulário será submetido.